# iOS 8 custom UIActivity image black background color

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I am trying to add a custom `UIActivity` of type `UIActivityCategoryAction` to `UIActivityController`. But in iOS 8, all of them are appearing with a black background.

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are *3 things* to note here:

1. image background,
2. image opaqueness,
3. image size.

---

### iOS 7

1. **Image background**:

Image background should be transparent.

2. **image opaqueness**

The "visible part" of the icon should be non transparent aka opaque. Note that any color information **won't be preserved**:

3. **image size**

Because the **image won't be scaled by the system if too small/big**, you have to provide appropriately sized image. I found image size `120px x 120px` to fit perfectly.

*Note: this size also takes icon padding into account.*

---

### iOS 8+

1. **Image background**:

Image background should be **white** to match the system `UIAction` icons but you can also use an arbitrary color.

2. **image opaqueness**

Same as in iOS 7, "visible" part of the icon should be non transparent aka opaque, however in iOS 8+ **color information will be preserved**.

3. **image size**

I am using image with size `240px x 240px`, but you can apply custom sized image because **system will automatically scalle-to-fill image if too small/big**.

---

### Wrap up

That said, if you want to support both iOS 7 and iOS 8+, you have to have 2 versions of custom `UIActivity` icon image.

For **iOS 7** you should use **120px x 120px** sized image with **transparent background**. *Note: find the size that best suits your needs.*

For **iOS 8+** you should use **custom sized** square image with **white background** and "visible" part of an arbitrary colour.

**Code example**

```
- (UIImage *)activityImage
{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity_icon_ios8"];
    }
    else {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity_icon"];
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great answer. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Any info on the icon displayed next to the activity on tapping "More"?

Comment: @rkunde Thanks! I haven't been able to find any documentation on this. I believe they will add it in the future.

Comment: @Xcoder I see what you mean. I think there is no way of customizing/providing a custom activity icon for "Activities" screen of ``UIActivityController``. At least for now.

Comment: iOS 8 icons do not need to have a white background. I could use any color, such as green.

Comment: @Pwner no one said that you can't use an arbitrary color for background. I said that the background should be white if you want to match the system UIAction icons.

Comment: I tried creating an image in iOS 9 that was 240x240 and it did not auto-scale down. I had to change it to 120x120

Comment: @zerotool I just tried and had no problems using 240x240 with iOS 9.2. It scales properly. I was using 240px x 240px PNG as 2x.

Comment: Looks like it auto scales down for UIActivityCategoryShare but not UIActivityCategoryAction

Comment: For settings image there is a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35680343/1545278) using `activitySettingsImage`, but it's undocumented at this moment