# iOS 7 & 8 custom activityImage differences

Tags: ios, sharing, uiactivity

Since iOS 7 we've included custom activityImages for sharing purposes through the `UIActivity` component. According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActivity/activityImage) official Apple documentation it states that every non-transparant pixel will be overlayed by a grey gradient. The images we used where mainly transparant (transparant pixels became white) except for the part that was useful (became grey).

If I run the same application in the newest XCode on iOS 8.4 it seems that this is different. Apple restricted the use of colours in iOS 7 with their grey overlay but apparently not in iOS 8. This results in 2 different images based on the iOS version running on the device. I can't seem to find any documentation about this change. The official documentation has not been adapted as well. So I am not sure if this is an Apple related **bug or a feature**.

**Will I really have to support 2 different kinds of images (one for iOS 7 and one for iOS 8) when I want to use custom activityImages?**

If someone can refer to some more information on this, please do so.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation still hasn't been updated, but you are correct, this is a change in iOS 8. That means your app should provide a different icon based on the iOS version.

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817265/ios-8-custom-uiactivity-image-black-background-color) to a related question for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! That's indeed a good brief recap. It just bothers me that this cannot be found in official resources somewhere.

Comment: I did that, but who knows how long I have to wait for a response. The community here is way faster ;)